# MongoDB/PyMongo: how to 'escape' parameters in regex search?

Tags: regex, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo and want to do a search for items starting with a certain sequence of characters. I might implement that like this:

```
items = collection.find({ 'key': '/^text/' })
```

This should work, but what if `text` is a variable? I could do something like:

```
items = collection.find({ 'key': '/^' + variable + '/' })
```

But now if the text in `variable` contains any characters with special regex meaning (such as `$`), the query no longer behaves as expected. **Is there a way to do some sort of parameter binding?** Do I have to sanitize `variable` myself? Is that even reliably possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to assemble the regex programmatically.  So either:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('^' + re.escape(variable))
items = collection.find({ 'key': regex })
```

OR

```
items = collection.find({'key': { '$regex': '^' + re.escape(variable) }})
```

Note that the code uses [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape the string in case it contains special characters.

Comment: I see you edited your post at the same time as I submitted my answer. Looks like we both came to the same conclusion: use the `re` module. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Here is the concept: you have to use [regex](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries)

```
items = collection.find({
     'key' : {
         $regex : yourRegex
     }
})
```