# $regex requires regular expression error Pymongo Stitch

Tags: javascript, regex, pymongo

Trying to query the database with this code:
I have a string within 'nameInput' that I want to find documents that contain it.

```
var arg = {"$and":[{"name":{'$regex' : nameInput, '$options' : 'i'}}, {"thing": selectedThing}]}
```

I plug in arg into the find() method and it returns this error:
 *errors.js:20 Uncaught (in promise) Error: $regex requires regular expression*

Any idea how this can be fixed? I've tried replacing nameInput by using the RegExp method in Javascript to no avail. (e.g new RegExp(nameInput, 'i'))

Comment: what version of pymongo are you using to develop?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to find a string within `nameInput` then you need to make that the field you do the regex on. Try this:

```
nameInput : { $regex : /pattern-you-want-to-find/, $options : ‘i’ } }
```

Apologies for the brief answer, but if provide a more detailed question and an example document I can try and help a little more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the problem is that I can't hard code it in.. im getting the nameInput variable's value from a text field on a webpage, which Im then passing in to do a contains query through pymongodb

Comment: @yasgari Can't hard code what in? `nameInput` is a `key` and the `value` is the variable you've pulled from a text file and then matched on...... So when you come to do your `$regex` `nameInput` would be classed as the `field` to which you then want to run your regex on the value within.

Comment: Let me elaborate further- I have a website with an html page containing several text fields for searching. The variable `nameInput` is set in the event handler for the form containing those textfields; its set to the value of the field users type in a name to search.  like so:  `nameInput = document.getElementById('gene').value;` So now since this variable contains the string I want to find, I want the DB to query and find any documents (in column `name`) containing the string passed in, stored in `nameInput`  Hope this helps! Apologies as this is my first post on here

Comment: The answer in this OP might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224753/mongodb-pymongo-how-to-escape-parameters-in-regex-search