# How to correctly design a regular expression in pymongo?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I use python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38), and pymongo 3.7.2.

In mongodb this works:

```
db.collection.find(
    {$and:[
    {"field":{$regex:"bon?"}},
    {"field":{$not:{$regex:"bon souple"}}},
    {"field":{$not:{$regex:"bon léger"}}}
    ]}
    )
```

So in pymongo I did the same as:

```
db.collection.find(
    {"$and":[
    {"field":{"$regex":"bon?"}},
    {"field":{"$not":{"$regex":"bon souple"}}},
    {"field":{"$not":{"$regex":"bon léger"}}}
    ]}
    )
```

but it indicates`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $regex has to be a string`.

So I tried this as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224753/mongodb-pymongo-how-to-escape-parameters-in-regex-search):

```
liste_reg=[
{'field': {'$regex': {'$not': re.compile('bon souple')}}}, 
{'field': {'$regex': {'$not': re.compile('bon léger')}}}, 
{'field': {'$regex': re.compile('bon?')}}
]
rslt=list(
    db.collection.find({"$and":liste_reg})
)
```

I noticed that even when there is no special character it indicates the same error:

```
liste_reg=[
{'field': {'$regex': {'$not': re.compile('bon souple')}}} #where no special char is present
]
rslt=list(
    db.collection.find({"$and":liste_reg})
)
```

So I tried to use `"/"` as:

```
liste_reg=[
{'field': {'$regex': {'$not':'/bon souple/'}}} #where no special char is present
#even tried re.compile('/bon souple/')
]
rslt=list(
    db.collection.find({"$and":liste_reg})
)
```

the same error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $regex has to be a string` still occurs.

What can I do?

SOME UPDATE OF MY RESEARCH OF SOLUTION

the core of the issue seems to be with `$not` because when I do:

```
liste_reg=[{'field': {'$regex': 'bon?'}}]
rslt=list(
    db.collection.find({"$and":liste_reg})
)
len(rslt)#gives 23 013, what is ok.
```

There is no error.

SOME SAMPLES

As asked by Emma I can give a sample, and it will explicit my request in mongo.
Normally I must have these modalities in the field:

- sec
- très léger
- léger
- bon léger
- bon
- bon souple
- souple
- très souple
- collant
- lourd
- très Lourd
- profond

The main problem for me is my spider did not parse correctly because I did not write a strong enough script for that.
Instead of obtaining just "bon", I obtain this kind of result:

```
{"_id":"ID1",
"field":"bon\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tnon",
...}
```

and that's an example between many others wrong parsing.
So that's why I want result that begins with `"bon?"` but not `"bon souple"` or `"bon léger"` because they have correct values, no `\n` or `\t`.

So as samples:

```
[{"_id":"ID1",
"field":"bon\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tnon"},
{"_id":"ID2",
"field":"bon\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tpremière"},
{"_id":"ID3",
"field":"bon\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t2ème"},
{"_id":"ID4",
"field":"bon souple"},
{"_id":"ID5",
"field":"bon léger"}]
```

Comment: @Emma I did an update with a sample of what you asked. Or at least what I think you asked.

Comment: @Emma as you said in your DEMO it works in it. But, I am not able to explain you why, when I write this in the mongo shell in robo3t `db.collection.find({"field":{$regex:"bon[^\s].+"}})` the first file which appears is `{
    "_id" : "364714",..., "field" : "bon léger"}`. I looked at View document in order to see if it is not an exception like `"bon\t\t\t\t\nléger"`, and actually this is really `"bon léger"`. In my mongo shell it takes the spacebar in consideration. Besides in pymongo I obtain an empty list with `len(list(db.geny_rapp.find({'etat_terrain': {'$regex': "bon[^\s].+"}})))`.

Comment: @Emma honestly I have another way to do to answer my problematic, but without regex, that's more complicated and I use the set and operations on set: setA-setB -> the set I want. But as I said it is more complicated and that's not the goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue.

Try doing this:

```
liste_reg=[
{'field': {'$not': re.compile('bon souple')}}, 
{'field': {'$not': re.compile('bon léger')}}, 
{'field': {'$regex': re.compile('bon?')}}
]
rslt=list(
    db.collection.find({"$and":liste_reg})
)
```

I just removed the `$regex` part of the query.

*Background*

I tried doing `{item["type"]: {"$not": item['name']}}` and pymongo returned a `$not needs a regex or a document` error.

So, I tried: `{item["type"]: {"$not": {"$regex": item['name']}}}` and pymongo returned a `$not cannot have a regex` error.

I found this SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/20175230/9069964 and here's what finally worked for me:

```
item_name = item["name"]
{item["type"]: {"$not": re.compile(item_name)}}
```

I had to ditch the "$regex" part and give "$not" my regex stuff.

Comment: That's great! It works, and that's totally in the spirit of my code. Besides it gives the way to use '$not' without avoiding it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a string literal with a negative look ahead. The example below should work as long as you have a carriage return (\r) after 'bon'.

```
import re
bon = re.compile(r'bon(?=\r)')
db.collection.find({'field': bon})
```

Comment: `len(list(db.collection.find({'field': {'$regex': re.compile(r'bon(?=\r)')}})))` gives me
19 files. While I expect 22242. I think I will answer my problematic with another way than only regex and use the properties of set objects.

Comment: Might be easier just to clean up your data. `bon_dirty = 'bon\r\n\t' bon_clean = bon_dirty.strip()`

Comment: Well I did a dump of my collection, and now it's clear, that's what I expect. It returns the same number of files than mongo with $not. But it's still mysterious why `re.compile()` does not work for me while it does for [others](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/FdFJWzmKfds).

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might be able to approach solving this problem, maybe without using the `$not` feature. For instance, if we wish to not have `bon souple` or `bon léger` which are `bon` followed by an space, we could maybe use an expression similar to:

```
"bon[^\s].+"
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gp60jX/1/)

I'm not so sure about what we wish to extract here, but I was just guessing that maybe we would want to swipe `bon` values not followed by an space and in between the `"`.

Also, we would likely want to look into regex query requirements and adjust our expressions to it, if necessary, such as with escaping or using capturing group:

```
(bon[^\s].+)
```

or:

```
"(bon[^\s].+)"
```

or:

```
\"(bon[^\s].+)\"
```

or:

```
([\s\S]*?)\"(bon[^\s].+)\"
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IpCFdn/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

I'm not quite sure if this would be what we might want or if it would be relevant, yet according to this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), we can try using:

```
{ name: { $regex: /([\s\S]*?)\"(bon[^\s].+)\"/, $options: "mi" } }
```

or:

```
{ name: { $regex: '([\s\S]*?)\"(bon[^\s].+)\"', $options: "mi" } }
```

---

#### db.collection.find

```
db.collection.find({"field":{ $regex: /(bon[^\s].+)/, $options: "mi" }})
```

or:

```
db.collection.find({"field":{ $regex: /(bon[^\s].+)/, $options: "si" }})
```

---

Reference:

#### [PyMongo $in + $regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867389/pymongo-in-regex)

#### [Performing regex Queries with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483318/performing-regex-queries-with-pymongo/3483399)

Comment: Doing `db.collection.find({"field":{$regex:"\"(bon[^\s].+)\"" }})` or `db.collection.find({"field":{$regex:"([\s\S]*?)\"(bon[^\s].+)\""}})` gives: `Fetched 0 record(s) in 55ms`. Note I entered `"\"(bon[^\s].+)\""` and not `\"(bon[^\s].+)\"`, same for `([\s\S]*?)\"(bon[^\s].+)\"`, because it raises error in mongo shell.

Comment: `db.collection.find({"field":{ $regex: /([\s\S]*?)\"(bon[^\s].+)\"/, $options: "mi" }})` no error, but result is 0.